# How to load JSON(path saved in csv) with Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark.
I can load the .json file in Spark. What if there are thousands of .json files in a folder. [picture of .json files in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyZM6.png)

And I have a csv file, which classifies the .json files with labels.[picture of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTxBk.png)

What should I do with Spark if I want to load and save the data.(for example.I want to load the first information in csv, but it is text information. But it gives the path of .json, and I want to load the .json, then save the output. So I will know the first Trusted label graph's json information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the JSON:

```py
jsonRDD = sql_context.read.json("path/to/json_folder/");
```

For **CSV** install `spark-csv` from here [Databricks' spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

```py
csvRDD = sql_context.read.load("path/to/csv_folder/",format='com.databricks.spark.csv',header='true',inferSchema='true')
```

Comment: Thanks. Another question. How can I make the thousands of .json work parallel? Map&Reduce?

Comment: Also, note that from 2.0.0 onwards parsing csv will be a part of Spark itself and you won't have to rely on spark-csv anymore.